# Javascript pass variable between beforesend & success

Tags: javascript, variables

This is my code:

```
$("#myform").ajaxForm({
    beforeSend: function() {
        var abcd = "hahah";
    },
    success: function(data){
        alert(abcd);
    }
});
```

How can I have the variable in `beforesend` to be accessible in `success`? I want the variable to be local so it does not mess with global variable. As soon as after success, that variable should be no longer in use anymore.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simplest general solution is to use an [IIFE](http://benalman.com/news/2010/11/immediately-invoked-function-expression/) to wrap "local" variables :

```
(function(){
    var abcd;
    $("#myform").ajaxForm({
        beforeSend: function() {
            abcd = "hahah"
        },
        success: function(data){
            alert(abcd);
        }
    });
})();
```

Comment: will the variable abcd still exist after success() has been called?

Comment: @treeno No : as soon as the callbacks aren't referenced anymore, the IIFE's scope can be garbaged with the variable it contains).

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:-

```
(function(){
var me = this;
$("#myform").ajaxForm({
    beforeSend: function() {
        me.abcd = "hahah"
    },
    success: function(data){
        alert(me.abcd);
        delete me.abcd;
    }
});
})();
```

Comment: You're adding abcd to the external context (`window`), thus polluting it. OP wanted to avoid to "mess with global variable".